# How to change query results to array

Tags: php, mysql

Ho do I change results from mysql database to an array to be used in other functions

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $query = "select * from users";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


    while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $user['identification'];
    }
}
```

I tried  `$lima = array($user['identification']);` but doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want a list of user identifications, in this case create an empty array outside the loop and add each entry as you fetch a row from the database...

```
$lima = array();
while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $lima[] = $user['identification'];
}
```

Note also that if you only want the `identification` column, you would be better to put this in your select rather than `*`...

```
$query = "select identification from users";
```

You could also look into [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to fetch all the data in one go rather than using a loop...

```
$lima = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

You can then use the list of values in something like...

```
foreach ( $lima as $value) { 
    $jake = preg_grep("/$concatedNum/", $value);
    echo $jake.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: hi.. thanks. So if I'm going to use the entire 'identification' row in a function, how do I go about it?  e.g  $jake1 = preg_grep("/[$concatedNum]+/", $lima);

Comment: I've added an example of how to use the values in the answer.

Comment: I need to use the 'identification' row array in a preg_grep function. Like I illustrated above. foreach( $lima as $value){ $jake1 = preg_grep("/[$concatedNum]+/", $value); Is this okay?

Comment: Should be OK, try it and see what happens.

Comment: Hi... thanks for the feedback. I have a little problem with this -->  $jake = preg_grep("/$concatedNum/", $lima);
  foreach($jake as $value){
   print $value;
  }
      It returns nothing.

Comment: I've updated the last example of the code, but not sure what your trying to achieve with this, but see if it echos the values your after.

Answer (score 0):

To access an element with a certain key in an array we use this syntax `$user['identification'];` When you are doing that in your while loop, It's like you want just to access the value at the **key** `identification` in the `$user` array after access It you are doing nothing special in your while loop.
To create an array with only the indenfication of each `user` you must add the value of `$user['identification']` to a new array and at a certain `index`. In PHP You don't have to declare a variable before you start using it, like I did bellow I append the value of `identification` key for each `user` to a new array `$lima` because It's an indexed array you don't have to specify the *index*. Just by not specifiying any thing within the bracket PHP will generate automaticaly a new index for each element added to the array

```
while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $lima[] = $user['identification'];
}
```

Comment: thanks... is $lima[] an array that can be used in say  $jake1 = preg_grep("/[$concatedNum]+/", $lima);

Comment: Avoid code-only answers, please. Provide also some explanation. You can see from OP's comment that it's actually needed.

Comment: @harrid Yes, you ca use $lima like that It's an array, if you want to retrieve only certain element within the $lima array. It's up to you to pass It to the preg_grep functiom

Comment: Hi Yves... the below code returns nothing. pls help. $jake = preg_grep("/$concatedNum/", $lima);
  foreach($jake as $value){
   print $value;
  }
      /